# 2002 Subaru Legacy, Grinding Sound

Tags: automatic-transmission, subaru, drivetrain, parking-brake

Just got home from work and put my car into park and heard a grinding sound.

The parking brake stopped working. I tried putting it into drive and got the same grinding sound.  It was as if something was scraping against the asphalt.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked under the vehicle to see if the ***is*** something dragging? Or was the scraping noise present without the vehicle moving?

Comment: Yeah it does it without moving and gets worse when giving it gas. Almost seems like it's not quite getting into gear? I looked underneath to make sure nothing was dragging, that no rocks were stuck anywhere or that anything was bent/broken and checked all my fluids.

Answer (score 1):

Check your e-brake drum shoes. They are located on the inside of the rear wheels. If the drum is rusted or the shoe (pad) is scraping it would make a scraping noise such as the one you described.

Comment: This could be helpful to some people, but in @stephen's comment he says the noise happens even without moving.